# Calculating React element height before mounting

Tags: reactjs

I have a set of items which are rendered into a list. Each item will have a different height when rendered. I need to know item's height in advance before it's mounted into the DOM. So the container should know height of each item it's rendering before they're rendered :)

Is it possible to calculate the height of React element before inserting it into the DOM, dynamically?

Comment: You could try [AutoSizer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/AutoSizer.md) from `react-virtualized`. Haven't tried it myself but based on the docs it seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't get the elements's height before they are rendered because The DOM API can't give you the height of elements it doesn't even know yet.

Are all the different heights totally random ? If not, you could make a guess based on the props object of each element.